# adding file to svn using ant

Tags: svn, ant

As I move from CVS to SVN I'm trying to add a file in svn using ant.

My **build.properties**:

```
svn.root=http://svn/projects2

svn.rsh=/usr/bin/ssh
```

My .xml script:

```
<svn>
            <add 
                path="${relative.metadata}/Build_@{product}_@{major}.@{minor.next}"
                cvsRoot="${svn.root}" 
                cvsRsh="${svn.rsh}" />

            <add 
                path="${relative.metadata}/Build_@{product}_@{major}.@{minor.next}/master-@{product}_@{major}.@{minor.next}.sql"
                cvsRoot="${svn.root}" 
                cvsRsh="${svn.rsh}" />

            <add 
                path="-q commit -m 'Adding the next build directory' ${relative.metadata}/Build_@{product}_@{major}.@{minor.next}"
                cvsRoot="${svn.root}"
                cvsRsh="${svn.rsh}" />

        </svn>
```

As you can see it's a mix of using CVS with SVN so I'm sure I was wrong in doing this.  I'm just trying to get a file committed into SVN using this type of script.  Am I making it more complicated than it really is?

Ok... I've done some research and this is what I have so far...

My build.properties contain this

svn.repo.url=http://svn.project.com/projects

My .xml is this now

```
<property name="svn.repository.url" value="${svn.repo.url}"/>

<svn>
      <add
          dir="${relative.metadata}/Build_@{product}_@{major}.@{minor.next}"/>

</svn>
```

So my question is now, what is missing for this operation to be successful ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [SVNAnt task](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svn.html) provided by tigris.org, especially the subcommand [`svn add`](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svntask.html#add).

So you should be able to do something like:

```
<svn>
  <add file="${relative.metadata}/Build_@{product}_@{major}.@{minor.next}"/>
</svn>
```

Answer (score -1):

use the SVN Add, then give the directory you want to add to the SVN.